# is there some sort of all-purpose logging tool I can download as a package?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, package-management, security, logs

As in, a tool that will give me easy to read logging information all in one convenient place, divvied up into categories. Logs for say, ssh daemon, user logins/logouts and other activity, installed applications, etc.

I'm just having a bit of trouble sorting through the existing logs for exactly what I'm looking for because they are usually just a giant jumble of things. In OSX for example, the console can be filtered by a text string but even that isn't too ideal; it would be nice if they were separated from the jump. Like some sort of directory where I can monitor everything important. Any suggestions?

I'm running a headless version of Ubuntu Server edition 12 btw. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Webmin may be what you're looking for.

It gives you a web login [open-able in common web browsers] into your computer once installed, default https://your.computer.location:10000 and then over HTTPS 
you can access the command line, manage different servers and services installed on your computer, user profiles, and other computer settings. Examples of what you can manage is the Apache server, FTP, SSH, and other servers, plus it has access to the MySQL tools.

Check out http://www.webmin.com/ for more details.

-Jared

Answer (score 0):

[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/download) is a very useful tool to collect logs from a bunch of different sources, and give combined results.  They have a version that is free for personal use.

Another useful tool is [Logwatch](http://www.logwatch.org), which gives you a daily summary in your inbox of all the logs it monitors, including apache, ftp, ssh, etc.